# Spotify - Firebase - user registration/login

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, spotify

Right now I am trying to create a Firebase User, by making a spotify sign in ( I would like to create a firebase user with the spotify credentials).
My main idea is to get the Spotify Data in the Front End and send that Data to the Backend.
The Firebase userid would be the same as the Spotify User ID. If somebody changed his Spotify Email, the userid aka spotifyuserid would be still the same. By comparing just the id's I could make a login, although the email could possibly be changed.
By comparing the IDs it's possible to change the email in the Firebase Database as well .
My First question is, is that a good Idea to implanted a Spotify - Firebase - user registration

Then I found that git hub profile. Basically he is implementing a spotify-auth-flow with Firebase and creating a Firebase user with the Spotify credentials

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/spotify-auth

I tried to test his code. But I run into an issue, because my redirect URL is wrong.
I really do not know what he means with 
Add the URL https://.firebaseapp.com/popup.html to the Redirect URIs of your Spotify app

that's my Firebase 
appId: "1:xxxxx:web:yyyyy"

I tried every possible combination and added them in my Spotify app. But nothing is working 
( https://1:xxxxx:web:yyyyy.firebaseapp.com/popup.html 
https://yyyyy.firebaseapp.com/popup.html .... (I tried every Combination)

That's the important part of the code 
My assumption is, that my redirect URL is wrong

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// @ts-ignore
//const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
admin.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId:"1:xxxxx:web:yyyyy",
  //credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  //databaseURL: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseio.com`,
});

// Spotify OAuth 2 setup
// TODO: Configure the `spotify.client_id` and `spotify.client_secret` Google Cloud environment variables.
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const Spotify = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: "xxxx",
  clientSecret: "xxxx",
  redirectUri: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com/popup.html`,
});
```